# Deleting a row completely from a dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, session, dataset

I have a remove button on my gridview. On Clicking the remove button , the row should be 
completely removed from the session. I am currently doing the following :

```
protected void gvMainLog_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Remove")
        {

            GridViewRow rowSelect = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            int rowindex = rowSelect.RowIndex;

            DataSet ds =  ((DataSet)Session["old"]);

            ds.Tables[0].Rows[rowindex].Delete();

            Session["old"] = ds;

            gvMainLog.DataSource = Session["old"];
            gvMainLog.DataBind();

        }
```

The problem is that :

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[rowindex].Delete();
```

removes only the content in that row. When I look at the dataset , it shows an empty row.

Is there a way I can remove the entire row, without it showing an empty row ?

Comment: have you tried datarow.Remove()? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.remove.aspx

Comment: You could try the [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.remove.aspx) method of the DataRowCollection object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try calling

```
ds.AcceptChanges()
```

after row.Delete().

Answer (score 11):

If you want to remove a single data row, RemoveAt is the easier option:

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
```

Oscar's answer is also correct, according to the [remarks for RemoveAt on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.removeat.aspx):

> When a row is removed, all data in that row is lost. You can also call the Delete method of the DataRow class to just mark a row for removal. Calling RemoveAt is the same as calling Delete and then calling AcceptChanges.

Comment: For me it was .RemoveAt(rowIndex) and not .Remove

Comment: @Krondorian Thanks for pointing this out.  I've edited my answer accordingly.  Both Remove and RemoveAt behave identicially; the only difference between the methods is the parameter you have to pass to identify the row being removed.