# Directly delete selected record in gird from database

Tags: c#, sql

I want delete selected row directly from database. I wrote this code but it doesn't work correctly.

Here is my code but it doesn't delete record from my SQL server local db;

```
MyDataSet.Tables["ProductTable"].Rows[gridView1.GetFocusedDataSourceRowIndex()].Delete();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting a row completely from a dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471189/deleting-a-row-completely-from-a-dataset)

Comment: how do you populate MyDataSet ?

Comment: Calling Delete on a DataRow doesn't delete the record in the database. It just mark that row with DataRowState.Deleted. You call  DataAdapter.Update method or  you call a specific method that deletes the row to remove it from the database table.

Comment: i try ds.AcceptChange(); but don't work

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution :

```
myDataSet = myWS.LookUp(sessionUserID, "UserID", "Users"); // Adapt this to the way you populate the dataset
            myDataTable = Tables["ProductTable"];
            DataRow drCurrent =MyDataSet.Tables["ProductTable"].Rows[gridView1.GetFocusedDataSourceRowIndex()]
            myDataSet.AcceptChanges() 
            drCurrent.Delete();
            myWS.UpdateDB(myDataSet);
```

Answer (score 1):

Double click on DataGridView; you get an event named `CellContentClick`.

```
try
{
    int x = int.Parse(datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[UserID.Index].Value.ToString());
    string query = "delete from productable where UserID=" + x;
    // now delete execute procedure
    MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully");
    // write code to bring record again.
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
}
```

Comment: remember if you didn't have named your columns, you can change (Cells.[UserID.Index]) to Cells[0].value.